# Formulario com enctype impossibilita leitura de input text e de upload de imagem

Tags: php, html, html5

Estava conseguindo fazer o upload de arquivos com meu formulário contendo apenas um input e do tipo file. No entanto,  surgiu-me a necessidade de fazer um form de cadastro de categorias que envia os dados da categoria para o banco de dados e a imagem para o servidor com o nome sendo o id. A partir daí surgiu o problema, segue meu código no momento:

```
<form method="POST" action="cadascatraiz.php" enctype="multipart/form-data">
  <div class="form-group">
    <div class="form-label-group">
      <input type="text" name="inputCatRaiz" id="inputCatRaiz" class="form-control" placeholder="Categoria Raiz" required="required" autofocus="autofocus">
      <label for="inputCatRaiz">Categoria Raiz</label>
    </div>
  </div>
    <br>
    <div class="form-group">
          <label>Arquivo:</label>
          <input type="file" name="arquivo" />
      </div>
  <input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-block" value="Cadastrar">
```

```
<?php 
    include 'conexao.php';
    $categoria =  htmlspecialchars(addslashes($_POST['inputCatRaiz']));

    $sql = "INSERT INTO tb_categoria (categoria) VALUES ('$categoria') ";

    if($con->query($sql)===TRUE){
        //código de um repósitorio
         // Pasta onde o arquivo vai ser salvo
        $_UP['pasta'] = '../eu/categorias/';

        // Tamanho máximo do arquivo (em Bytes)
        $_UP['tamanho'] = 1024 * 1024 * 2; // 2Mb

        // Array com as extensões permitidas
        $_UP['extensoes'] = array('png', 'gif', 'svg');

        // Renomeia o arquivo? (Se true, o arquivo será salvo como .jpg e um nome único)
        $_UP['renomeia'] = TRUE;

        // Array com os tipos de erros de upload do PHP
        $_UP['erros'][0] = 'Não houve erro';
        $_UP['erros'][1] = 'O arquivo no upload é maior do que o limite do PHP';
        $_UP['erros'][2] = 'O arquivo ultrapassa o limite de tamanho especifiado no HTML';
        $_UP['erros'][3] = 'O upload do arquivo foi feito parcialmente';
        $_UP['erros'][4] = 'Não foi feito o upload do arquivo';

        // Verifica se houve algum erro com o upload. Se sim, exibe a mensagem do erro
        if ($_FILES['arquivo']['error'] != 0) {
        die("Não foi possível fazer o upload, erro:<br />" . $_UP['erros'][$_FILES['arquivo']['error']]);
        exit; // Para a execução do script
        }

        // Caso script chegue a esse ponto, não houve erro com o upload e o PHP pode continuar

        // Faz a verificação da extensão do arquivo
        $extensao = strtolower(end(explode('.', $_FILES['arquivo']['name'])));
        if (array_search($extensao, $_UP['extensoes']) === false) {
        echo "Por favor, envie arquivos com as seguintes extensões: jpg, png ou gif";
        }

        // Faz a verificação do tamanho do arquivo
        else if ($_UP['tamanho'] < $_FILES['arquivo']['size']) {
        echo "O arquivo enviado é muito grande, envie arquivos de até 2Mb.";
        }

        // O arquivo passou em todas as verificações, hora de tentar movê-lo para a pasta
        else {
        // Primeiro verifica se deve trocar o nome do arquivo
        if ($_UP['renomeia'] == true) {
        // Cria um nome baseado no UNIX TIMESTAMP atual e com extensão .jpg

        $sql = "SELECT id FROM tb_categoria WHERE categoria = '$categoria'";
        $rolo = $con->query($sql)->fetch_assoc();
        $nome_final = rolo['id'].'.jpg';
        } else {
        // Mantém o nome original do arquivo
        $nome_final = $_FILES['arquivo']['name'];
        }

        // Depois verifica se é possível mover o arquivo para a pasta escolhida
        if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES['arquivo']['tmp_name'], $_UP['pasta'] . $nome_final)) {
        // Upload efetuado com sucesso, exibe uma mensagem e um link para o arquivo
        echo "Upload efetuado com sucesso!";
        echo '<br /><a href="' . $_UP['pasta'] . $nome_final . '">Clique aqui para acessar o arquivo</a>';
        } else {
        // Não foi possível fazer o upload, provavelmente a pasta está incorreta
        echo "Não foi possível enviar o arquivo, tente novamente";
        }

        }
        $_SESSION['cadas_cat']='OK';
    }else{
        $_SESSION['cadas_cat']='ERRO';
    }
    $con->close();
    header("location:novacatraiz.php");
?>
```

Comment: Qual seria o problema apresentado?

Comment: No caso, quando tem apenas o input de imagem ou apenas o de texto eles funcionam corretamente, porém quando o input dos dois tipos de dados estão no mesmo form, apenas o cadastro no banco é realizado...

Comment: Já tentou sem esse redirecionamento no final?

Comment: fica só em branco, não exibi nenhuma das mensagens, pelo que eu pesquisei acredito que seja problema desse "enctype" no form, mas ele que permite fazer o upload de imagem...

Comment: Então ele não tá entrando no primeiro IF.

Comment: Ele entra no "if($con->query($sql)===TRUE){" e cadastra a categoria mas a imagem não vai pra pasta. Isso que não estou conseguindo entender

Comment: Como vc sabe que está  entrando no IF se não exibe nenhuma das mensagens que tem dentro dele?

Comment: Por ter a SESSION setada dentro desse if, quando faz o redirecionamento pra página no final eu valido isso e além disso verifico no banco de dados...

Comment: No final do IF tem outro IF...ELSE cada qual com um `echo`... Acho que se tivesse entrando nesse primeiro IF, um dos dois ECHOs deveria ser exibido. Se a tela fica em branco, me leva a insistir que não está entrando nesse IF. :/

Comment: Entendo... Eu realmente não sei o que fazer, por que em todos os lugares que eu vi falava sobre esse enctype, você teria alguma ideia de como contornar isso?

Comment: Tem que ter certeza de que está entrando nesse IF. Coloque um `echo 'entrou no if';` logo no início desse IF e comente a linha do redirecionamento. Veja se mostra esse `echo`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Companheiro, seu código está certinho... mas faça o seguinte, eu testei aqui em casa, a situação de você já recuperar o ID diretamente do último INSERT da conexão atual, daí você poderia remover algumas partes do código, mas analise antes de remover algo

Como solução faça o seguinte.

```
// Comente isto por enquanto...
// $sql = "SELECT id FROM tb_categoria WHERE categoria = '$categoria'";
// $rolo = $con->query($sql)->fetch_assoc();
/* $nome_final = rolo['id'] . '.jpg'; */
// Teste isso como solução...
$nome_final = mysqli_insert_id($con) . '.jpg';
```

A parte do select ficaria inútil, pois você já resgataria o ID por meio da conexão ativa.

Comment: Muito obrigado, funcionou perfeitamente!